# Issues converting .htaccess to Nginx configuration for PHP scripts

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I have an .htaccess file that I'm trying to convert so it can be run on my Nginx server.

I'm having two primary problems:

#### 1. I'm not sure how to convert some lines

#### 2. I don't know where to put the Nginx configuration code

Here are the lines I'm having issues converting:

```
 Options All -Indexes

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page_request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I've tried some online converters, but they don't seem to be working.

Also, once I've converted the lines, where do I put them? I assume I need to place them in the `mysite.conf` file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`, but within that file, do I just put them within the `server {}` block?

Thanks a lot for any help you can give me.

### Edit: Here's the conf file

```
 server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name www.subdomain.domain.tld subdomain.domain.tld;
    access_log /var/log/subdomain.domain.tld.log;

    location / {
        root /srv/www/subdomain.domain.tld/public_html;
        index index.html index.php;
        }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/subdomain.domain.tld/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?page_request=$uri;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Doing some nginx research, came across this, give this a shot and see if it works as you expect:

```
location / {
    # other code below this line
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?page_request=$uri;
}
```

Basically the try_files is the if statement, it tries the regular file first, if it cannot find it, it tries it as a directory, if it cannot find that it sends it to the last argument.

---

**OLD**

Have you tried using a service like: http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/

It outputs:

```
#ignored: condition 0
#ignored: condition 1
if ($rule_0 = "2"){
rewrite /RewriteRule ^/(.*)$;
}
```

For the data you provided.

Where you put them is inside the:

```
server {

}
```

Since this is not for a specific `location` you would just put it after the default stuff. There is order of operations to be had, so yea. It can be inside of a location, if you have more than one location type bit. For nginx, I would probably put this under the .php location definition.

Comment: Yes, I tried this site, but this code doesn't work. In fact, the commented "ignored: condition 0" means the convert is ignoring lines in my code. Running this code yields the error: `nginx: [emerg] invalid variable name in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/atr3.com.conf:38`.

Comment: Can you post the atr3.com.conf? It would make it a bit easier to see what may be going wrong.

Comment: I just edited my question, added it in. (subdomain.domain.tld is in place of the actual data)

Comment: Also, I also know the code from the converter can't work because it needs to be sending the string as a page_request $_GET variable to PHP.

Comment: Hmm... That seems like it makes sense now, but I'm still getting 404 errors while trying this.

Comment: @archio hmm, I updated the code, that may work, not sure because of the lack of last;  directive. Give that a try though and see. If not I will see what else I can find.

Comment: Ah. Should I put that after the PHP location? I just updated my question with my current code.

Comment: I am not sure, try it with both and see what comes. I think putting it after the .php location would be fine, unless your pages for the `page_request` variable end in .php, then I would put it before so it doesn't enter into that location. And actually the more I think of it, I would put it before.

Comment: I put them both before and after, and for some reason it doesn't work. I just checked the nginx error logs, and the problem seems to be that nginx is looking for `/srv/www/subdomain.domain.tld/public_html/page` and not finding it, instead of using the index.php?page_request.

Comment: Ok, I will see if I cannot setup an nginx server real fast and give it a try and see what comes.

Comment: Alright, I think I got er figured out. Move that into the `location / { }` directive and this should work properly. @Archio

Comment: Yup, that did it! Thanks so much, I really appreciate the effort.